# Can we export query result in postgres using spooling command?

Tags: postgresql

I want to export query result in csv file. I used query select * from entity
COPY (select * from entity) TO 'D:/text.csv' WITH DELIMITER AS '|' CSV HEADER;
and it workd.. But I want to know if I can do it using spool command like we do it in oracle..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

PostgreSQL doesn't have a SPOOL command. You can direct output to a file using COPY (as you've discovered) or by using psql. [Psql is a command-line tool](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/app-psql.html). It's not a re-implementation of Oracle's SPOOL.

From the OS prompt

```
psql -o filename -c 'select * from your_table_name;'
```

You might have to specify the username and database name, depending on how your login is set up.

From the psql prompt

```
\o filename
select * from your_table_name;
```

There are options to control the output. See the -F and -R options, especially.

Comment: I tried second one.. But it did not work.. Anyway can you tell me if there is no any spool command in postgresql??

Comment: That's the very first thing I told you: PostgreSQL doesn't have a SPOOL command. You send output to a file with either COPY or with psql. Read the PostgreSQL documentation (linked above) and try again. Like most command-line tools, it's a little picky.

Comment: You can use \o command within Postgres script so that output from individual commands can be redirected to different log files

Comment: Beware for large queries it might say out of RAM unless you set the fetch count first (ex: `\set FETCH_COUNT 10000`)