# Python Flask using tables created in separate SQL file?

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a SQL file that creates the tables for my database in PostgreSQL. How can I connect to this database in Flask and use it? All tutorials I am looking at online create the tables in Flask itself using SQLAlchemy, but in my case I have this done in a separate SQL file. I don't know if it is worth getting rid of the SQL file with the database schema and creating the tables in Flask itself instead and only using Flask & SQLAlchemy.

Answer (score 0):

To read sql statements from a file you can use **text()** function:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import text
```

**Small Demo**:
This a sql file kept in the current directory, it can be put anywhere and path to it needs to be provided.

```
cat file.sql
create table testfile(id int ,txt varchar(10));
insert into testfile values(1,'one');
```

Read the file and execute using sqlalchemy:

```
>>> from sqlalchemy import create_engine
>>> from sqlalchemy.sql import text
>>> 
>>> engine = create_engine('postgresql+pg8000://<username>:<password>@<dbhost>/postgres')
>>> with engine.connect() as pgconn:
...     file = open("./file.sql")
...     stmts = text(file.read())
...     pgconn.execute(stmts)
<sqlalchemy.engine.cursor.LegacyCursorResult object at 0x107a67970>
```

Result inside the DB:

```
postgres=# \d testfile
                     Table "public.testfile"
 Column |         Type          | Collation | Nullable | Default
--------+-----------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 id     | integer               |           |          |
 txt    | character varying(10) |           |          |

postgres=# select * from testfile;
 id | txt
----+-----
  1 | one
(1 row)
```

Comment: I have the same question. I'm using flask_sqlalchemy  and wondering if I can use .sql files to generate the tables.

Comment: @fpolig01 , what do you mean by "generate the tables"?  Is it "Create table" or "Load Table with data"?

Comment: both, I have about 5 .sql files that create tables and 1 .sql file which loads data into the newly created table. I managed to get it working by using db.engine.connect and then executing the sql file.